# array.push only the last variable in a for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, frontend

i'm actually asking myself why the following code is not working properly i found the solution but it's a bit tricky and i don't like this solution

Here is the code and the problem:

```
    function powerSet( list ){
        var set = [],
            listSize = list.length,
            combinationsCount = (1 << listSize),
            combination;

        for (var i = 1; i < combinationsCount ; i++ ){
            var combination = [];
            for (var j=0;j<listSize;j++){
                if ((i & (1 << j))){
                    combination.push(list[j]);
                }
            }
            set.push(combination);
        }
        return set;
    }

    function getDataChartSpe(map) {
        var res = {};

        for (var i in map) {
            console.log("\n\n");
            var dataSpe = {certif: false,
                experience: 0,
                expert: false,
                grade: 1,
                last: 100,
                name: undefined 
            };
            var compMatchList = [];
            for (var j in map[i].comps_match) {
                var tmp = map[i].comps_match[j];
                compMatchList.push(tmp.name)
            }
            var tmpList = powerSet(compMatchList);
            var lol = [];
            lol.push(map[i].comps_match);
            for (elem in tmpList) {
                console.log("mdr elem === " + elem + " tmplist === " + tmpList);
                var tmp = tmpList[elem];
                dataSpe.name = tmpList[elem].join(" ");
                lol[0].push(dataSpe);
            }
            console.log(lol);
        }
        return res; 
    }
```

now here is the still the same code but working well :

```
    function powerSet( list ){
        var set = [],
            listSize = list.length,
            combinationsCount = (1 << listSize),
            combination;

        for (var i = 1; i < combinationsCount ; i++ ){
            var combination = [];
            for (var j=0;j<listSize;j++){
                if ((i & (1 << j))){
                    combination.push(list[j]);
                }
            }
            set.push(combination);
        }
        return set;
    }


    function getDataChartSpe(map) {
        var res = {};
        var mapBis = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(map));

        for (var i in map) {
            var compMatchList = [];
            for (var j in map[i].comps_match) {
               var tmp = map[i].comps_match[j];
               compMatchList.push(tmp.name)
           }
           var tmpList = powerSet(compMatchList);
           mapBis[i].comps_match = [];
           for (elem in tmpList) {
               tmpList[elem].sort();
               mapBis[i].comps_match.push({certif: false,
                   experience: 0,
                   expert: false,
                   grade: 1,
                   last: 100,
                   name: tmpList[elem].join(", ")});
           }
       }
       return mapBis;
    }
```

Actually it's a bit disapointig for me because it's exactly the same but the 1st one doesn't work and the second one is working.

so if anyone can help me to understand what i'm doing wrong it'll be with pleasure

ps: i'm sorry if my english is a bit broken

Comment: @Rajesh this is in no way a duplicate of that; it doesn't have anything to do with closures.

Comment: There's no point to that `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(map))` thing, I don't think.

Comment: if you're not sure if it will be a string or not, that makes sure it will definitely be an object. unless you're using jquery tho there really no reason to expect that it would be anythign other than a sttring

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, you build **one** `dataSpe` object and re-use it over and over again. Each time this runs:

```
            lol[0].push(dataSpe);
```

you're pushing a reference to the same single object onto the array.

The second version of the function works because it builds a **new** object each time:

```
           mapBis[i].comps_match.push({certif: false,
               experience: 0,
               expert: false,
               grade: 1,
               last: 100,
               name: tmpList[elem].join(", ")});
```

That object literal passed to `.push()` will create a new, distinct object each time that code runs.

Comment: so what is the best way to build a new object ?

Comment: @FrançoisCugy your second piece of code does it correctly. I'll add to the answer.

Comment: Ok, but i mean this is a bit dirty that way isn't it ?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with that. It's a very common idiom.